# How can I access an item's properties in a QtQuick ListView by it's index?

Tags: qml

Lets say I want to change the color of the second Rectangle item in the listview to red.
How can I do it?

Here is my ListView:

```
ListView {  

        id: myList  
        model: myDataModel  

        delegate: Rectangle { 

               color: "green"
               height: 20
               width: 100

               onClicked{
                   //Do something
               }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it!

> var *myListItemObject* = ListView.contentItem.children[1]
>    *myListItemObject*.color = "red"